# How to ensure codes in FastAPI's lifespan is run in only one of the workers for Uvicorn?

Tags: python, fastapi, apscheduler, uvicorn

I would like to add a scheduled job in FastAPI and I have put the scheduler setup and shutdown codes in the `lifespan` of the FastAPI app. However, I notice that both workers are running the scheduler independently.

Is there any way I can ensure only one worker works on the scheduled job?

Sample code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import uvicorn

def test():
    print(f"Test scheduler {datetime.now()}")
    
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler() 
    
    scheduler.add_job(test, trigger="cron", second="0-30")
    scheduler.start()
        
    yield
    
    scheduler.shutdown()
    
app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", workers=2)
```

Output, where `test()` is run twice per second when I only want it to run once per second:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started parent process [34952]
INFO:     Started server process [34957]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Started server process [34958]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:15.001191
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:15.001314
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:16.000480
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:16.001643
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:17.000901
Test scheduler 2024-02-21 14:51:17.002765
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [34958]
INFO:     Finished server process [34957]
INFO:     Stopping parent process [34952]
```

Comment: Each worker is a separate instance, so if you want only one of them to run the scheduler, you'll need to coordinate that in some way, and you'll have to decide how to handle it if the worker running the scheduler restart. It might make more sense to run the scheduler as a separate process if it doesn't complicate things too much. Otherwise, you can possibly use a database or redis to register the pid that handles the scheduling, and check if that pid is still alive - and if not, start the scheduler. You might want to use the scheduler to check whether a scheduler is handling that task as well

Comment: Following @MatsLindh words, you can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/) and [Celery Beat](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found that it may be a better idea for me to start a `BackgroundScheduler` instead of an `AsyncIOScheduler`, and start it in the main function instead so the scheduler is configured in the parent process. Only 1 scheduler will be created in this case.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from datetime import datetime
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import uvicorn

def test():
    print(f"Test scheduler {datetime.now()}")
    
app = FastAPI()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler() 
    
    scheduler.add_job(test, trigger="cron", second="0-30")
    scheduler.start()

    uvicorn.run("main:app", workers=2)

    scheduler.shutdown()
```